# How to calculate the variance of a field in Hive?

Tags: hive

I want to get the variance value of a column from source table.
What is the function to do this in Hive? Like the udf function of "avg".

```
select udf_function(column) from sourcetable;
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you check the [Hive Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the variance(col) function which returns the variance of a numeric column in the group.  [This page](http://hadooptutorial.info/hive-aggregate-functions/) has some examples like: select variance(sal) from Tri100;